# Twitter Oauth question

Tags: twitter, oauth

I've read through documentation where possible but unable to figure out this basic question. When using Oauth with Twitter in my web application, does it require the user to be logged into Twitter everytime?

For example, if a user authorises their account with my website, in future sessions, if they complete an action that posts to their twitter stream, will this occur without any problems, or would they need to re-sign in via Twitter?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OAuth authorization actually allows *your application* to access their account whenever it wants. So the users do not even need to be there doing something with your web application to allow it to tweet something or such.

Your application is then able to use the key and token which it received in the authorization process to tell Twitter any time "hey, I am authorized to use this account" and basically works as the application's personal login credentials for that account.

Answer (score 3):

No, they only need to be logged into Twitter when they go through the initial OAuth authorization.  After that, your site talks directly to the Twitter API using tokens that it saved from earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I've setup a test-case and it looks like I was a bit wrong:

oauth_token, oauth_token_secret are unique for each user and they never change, so if you store them in your database you can reuse them. No matter if the user is logged in to twitter or not.

Answer (score 2):

No, they will normally not need to re-authorize.  If the token is revoked, however, they will, and your application needs to be able to handle this (by allowing them to do so).  In general, this is true for any SSO system.

A twitter user can explicitly revoke an application's token at the provided [page](http://twitter.com/account/connections).